# Docker copy on write with big files

Tags: docker

We are using docker with big files(database) and we want to store these files as a part of an image.
The problem is when files change and we want to commit changes to the image. Usually only part of the file changes and we would like docker to save only the differences.

Copy on write seems to work on the block level as long as we don't commit changes.
When we execute docker commit, the size of the commit is the sum of size of files being changed.

We are using:

**Storage Driver**: devicemapper

**Pool Name**: docker-thinpool

**Library Version**: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2016-06-09)

Is there a Storage Driver that is capable of saving (docker commit) changes on a block level, in other words does not save the whole file if only a small part changes?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Often questions can be answered faster and more accurately by providing a code sample. This might be the case for your question too. Please read this if so: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The [device mapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) storage driver works at the block level, and should do exactly what you want:

> Updating existing data uses a copy-on-write operation. Because Device Mapper is a block-based technology these operations occur at the block level. For example, when making a small change to a large file in a container, the devicemapper storage driver does not copy the entire file. It only copies the blocks to be modified. Each block is 64KB.

If you're using the Commercially Supported Docker Engine, `devicemapper` is the supported driver for RHEL and CentOS in the [compatibility matrix](https://success.docker.com/Help/Compatibility_Matrix), but the backend is in the mainline kernel, so it should run on other distros.

Answer (score -1):

Raw database files shouldn't really be on the COW layer, nor should they be committed to an image.

This sort of data is really what the volume system was designed for. Use normal database processes to populate the data and take backups. The image should contain the database software, and the volume should contain the state.

Comment: Well ... as far as I understand data volume is per container?
If I have a 100GB big database and want to create 10 identical running databases, how much space would i need?

If I store data in the image, I only need around 120 GB. 
100 GB for initial data that is common to all 10 databases, and around 2 GB for each running instance.
How much space would I need if I used datavolume? If I understand correctly 10 x 100 GB.

If i forgot to mention, I don't need the data to be persistent after the container has finished.
However i do need to (sometimes) save the state of the data.